# Syntax error in module 'lambda_function' for random.choices?

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am very new to AWS Lambda and I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. When I run this:

```
def chooseRndBook():
    os.chdir("sources") #the folder name which has the .txt files
    dir = os.getcwd()
    bookSet = os.listdir(dir)
    try:
        bookSet.remove('.DS_Store')

    #to randomly choose a book from the directory
    selectedBookFile = random.choice(bookSet)
    return selectedBookFile
```

I get this error:

```
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 37)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\" Line 37\n        selectedBookFile = random.choice(bookSet)\n"
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It runs perfectly on my device but not on AWS smh. I am trying to get the list of all .txt files within the folder, make a list of them, and select a random element from this list.

Comment: you dont have an except ... I do not believe it will run in any interpretter ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem in you case is not with the `random.choice`, but rather in invalid `try/except` block, which is missing `except` block. It should look like this:

```py
...
try:
  bookSet.remove('.DS_Store')
except:
  # Here implement error handler

selectedBookFile = random.choice(bookSet)
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, dude. This is quite embarrassing lmao.